# I’m not having any free time today

Tags: grammar

Can I say the below sentence? Is it correctly?

> I'm sorry I’m not having any free time today.

Or are there other better constructions?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the construction using the present participle is not idiomatic.

Native English speakers would say:

> I'm sorry (but) I don't have any free time today.

**I am not having...** would be used to describe an activity or situation, as in:

> I am not having much fun
>   I am not having much luck with this
>   I am not having lunch at the club today..

It just doesn't work with **free time**.

Comment: Some native speakers would say "I'm sorry (but) I haven't any free time today."

Comment: I understand that there is also another way.

"I have no free time today."

If we compare "I don't have any free time today" vs "I have no free time today" is the first one more emotional?

Maybe you can say which version is more used.

Comment: Both versions are popular and idiomatic. Neither expresses any obvious emotion. That would depend on the speaker's voice.